# Archiving CSS "box-shadow" like outcome in Swift with UIView

Tags: ios, css, swift, uiview

I am trying to replicate the look and feel of the CSS `box-shadow` property with a generic UIView.

For reference, here is the CSS line:

```
box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.30); #h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color
```

Here is what I am doing in iOS with a generic `UIView`:

```
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 12)//Blur
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.30
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0 //V-shadow
```

However, as seen below, the effect is not similar:

[image]

Specifically, the iOS shadow does not extend a bit to the top as the CSS shadow. My main goal is to fix this issue so the shadow extends a bit over the top part of the view. Any pointers here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `.shadowOffset` isn't the "blur" as you have it labeled. It's the x/y offset the shadow moves from its source. Try this:

```
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
```

You'll immediately see what I mean.

If you play around with the values you *might* get to a point that's close enough for you. Try:

```
    theView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 8)
    theView.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0
```

for a start.

Comment: Great suggestion. Definitely tweaking it would be the way go about it. I was wondering if there is a more direct CSS -> UIView property to go about doing this without modifying the CSS inputs, or if thats not possible because iOS uses a different set of standards.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "different set of standards." You're trying to apply web-browser based formatting to iOS UIKit objects. I expect you'll run into many situations where the 'native' iOS UI elements are not going to exactly match - nor be identically defined - as CSS properties.